# VC 6 C++ Exception handling, nTryBlocks=0, pTryBlockMap=0 , how?why?

Tags: decompilation, c++, callstack

I'm trying to decompile an old binary (about 20 year old).

The program uses exceptions.

I found some FuncInfo but they do not contain any pTryBlockMap and nTryBlocks is 0.

I've tried many options on the VC6 compiler but I could not get this result.

The stack doesn't look like a regular stack:

```
...
SEH handler
scope table
Try Level
saved EBP
return address
```

But it looks like:

```
...
SEH handler
Try level
return address
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve this and why it would have been like that ?

SEH Handler is :

```
MOV        EAX,DAT_00412c90
JMP        ___CxxFrameHandler
```

FuncInfo@00412c90

```
19930520
00000005
00412cb0
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

Comment: What is the SEH handler called? Do you have a link to the binary?

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky Sorry, I can't provide a link to the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when there are no try/catch blocks in a function, the compiler may generate a FunctionInfo structure and register a C++EH handler (such as `__CxxFrameHandler`). This is necessary, for example, to destruct automatic (stack-allocated) C++ objects going out of scope, or cleaning up a partially constructed object in a constructor. In such functions there will be no try blocks but you should see non-zero `pUnwindMap` with pointers to unwind funclets containing calls to destructors of stack objects, i.e. something like:

```
lea ecx, [ebp-2Ch]
jmp std::string::~string
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. And the difference in the stack seems to be an optimization option for the compiler (/Ox).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was so obvious - I just haven't read the C++ standard and was writing `throw()` specification thinking it would allow all exceptions - instead it turned out it was the exact opposite.

And yes this `throw` function specification is what is causing those zero TryBlockMap  with more than one Unwind entries. Here is a VC++ 6.0 (and later) compilable example (view dissasembly of `f`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct B {
    int a, b;
};

struct B1 {
    B1() {};
    B1(const B1& tmp) {
        a1 = tmp.a1;
        printf("B1::B1 copy constr\n");
    }
    ~B1() {
        printf("~B1()\n");
    }
    int a1, b1;
};

struct A : B, B1 {
    int b, c;
};

struct A f() throw(int) {
    struct A tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    f();
}
```

With two unwind entries. The tricky part in that scenario is that `throw` specification is not added to the type of the function so even if you have debug symbols (PDB) - you still will have your head banging against the wall.

EDIT: Actually the above example won't work for newer versions of MSVC - if you want to do it there you would need to add a `try` - `catch` block encapsulating the `f()` call.

Also the `class A` and all of it's parents were a test case for [another question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/what-is-the-mdisp-field-in-rtti-for-throw-used-for) related to the topic of C++ exception if you want to learn more but otherwise I don't think this exact structure is necessary to trigger the generation of FunctionInfo with zero TryBlocks. There just need to be something going on in `f` I think.